# How to show a background image outside of ui-page, in side columns

Tags: jquery-mobile

I try to reuse my jQuery Mobile Website for smartphones now for big screens.
Thanks to this forum I could shrink the main Content column/space, so I think its easier to read.
But on both sides there is now an empty space, where I would like to show a backgroundimage.

I tried to use the body tag, ui-page,and body.ui-mobile-viewport

I could get a background for the middle column, the content space, what is not what I want, but no background for the two side columns.

Any idea how to show a background image in the side columns?

```
<style>
/* Breitenanpassung PC, width change fr pc */
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.1em){
        .ui-page{
            width: 45em !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            position: relative !important;
            border-right: 0.3em #666 outset !important;
            border-left: 0.3em #666 outset !important;
            background : url('http://beta.mondkalender-mobil.de/templates/Mondkalender-mobil/images/hintergrund_breit.gif');

        }
</style>`
```

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvvwH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background for the whole document `body`, JQM will take care to set the background for the current `page`:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.1em) {
  .ui-page:not(.ui-dialog) {
    width: 45em !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    border-right: 0.3em #666 outset !important;
    border-left: 0.3em #666 outset !important;
  }
  .ui-mobile-viewport {
    background : url('http://beta.mondkalender-mobil.de/templates/Mondkalender-mobil/images/hintergrund_breit.gif');
  }
}
```